# Is it possible to use pipe (||) to set default parameters inside JavaScript object value

Tags: javascript, pipe, javascript-objects, default-value

```
const empiUpdateObject = {
          "parameters": {
            "bloodGroup": bloodCodeArray
              .map(bg => bg.code)
              .filter(bc => bc.toUpperCase() === bloodType.toUpperCase())
              .pop() || bloodType
          }
        }
```

If the defined array did not retrieve can I use '||' to set a default value to the object property

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I did and it worked  `function setValue(arg){
    console.log(arg);
    const obj = {
        name: 'default' || arg
    }
    console.log(obj);
}

setValue(); ` But I'm not sure can It be used as a standard way to set default values

Comment: *expression* || *expression* works in any context an *expression* is valid, including the value side of a property initializer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function setValue(arg){
    console.log(arg);
    const obj = {
        name: arg || 'default'
    }
    console.log(obj);
}

setValue('Pointy');
```

Please note this solution only works as long as false or falsy values are not required to be displayed. And the solution will only show true / truthy values.